# What is this application tiling mode I keep accidentally activating?

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally get this shown about a dozen times a day. I am using a trackpad and have no idea how I am doing it, only that it is very irritating. It seems like maybe I'm brushing my trackpad inadvertently, maybe while typing.

It causes open applications to tile, ESC causes it to close. There's also some sort of timeline slider thing on the right, which I do not understand at all.

What is this functionality called, and what are the standard shortcuts/gestures used to activate it?

(Note: I blurred it for security, it is not blurred at all in real life)

[image: tt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Windows Timeline.

You can activate it by pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: So I'm definitely not using that keyboard shortcut when I do it by accident - often I'll just be typing or whatever. Is there some mouse/trackpad gesture for it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy "Swipe up with three fingers: Show all recent activity and open windows via Windows Timeline."

Comment: @Mr.Boy [How to Use Touchpad Gestures for Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/370238/how-to-use-touchpad-gestures-for-windows-10/)